# Convert MYSQL command line query to inline php query

Tags: php, mysql

tI'm almost there in getting MySQL to do a geoip lookup in the locally stored maxmind database.  Instructions I've been following work when using the command line mysql > syntax for retrieving records. such as:

```
mysql> SELECT   glc.*
   FROM     geoip_blocks gbl
            JOIN geoip_locations glc
            ON       glc.glc_id = gbl.gbl_glc_id
   WHERE    gbl_block_start <= INET_ATON('149.156.1.4')
   ORDER BY gbl_block_start DESC
   LIMIT    1\G
```

However, I am having difficulty translating this to a mysql query in a php script.

I've tried:

```
`Select glc.* from geoip_blocks gbl JOIN geoip_locations glc ON glc.glc_id = gbl.gbl_glc_id WHERE    gbl_block_start <= INET_ATON('149.156.1.4') ORDER BY gbl_block_start DESC LIMIT 1\G`
```

But this doesn't work.  I'm sure this is an easy fix but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1):

The `mysql` command-line has a `\G` macro, but no such thing exists in raw SQL. Leave that out. It's not necessary to include a `;` either.

Answer (score 0):

Your php script should look something like this:

```
//set connection up
$mysql = new mysqli('mysql_server', 'mysql_user_name', 'mysql_password','mysql_DB');

//query
$sql = "SELECT glc.*
        FROM geoip_blocks gbl
        JOIN geoip_locations glc ON glc.glc_id = gbl.gbl_glc_id
        WHERE gbl_block_start <= INET_ATON('149.156.1.4')
        ORDER BY gbl_block_start DESC
        LIMIT 1";  

//run query & store result
$result = $mysql->query($sql);

//take a look at the results
if($result){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

        var_dump($row);

    }
}
```